# Access dropdownlist value which is kept outside listview?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I have a listview and a dropdownlist ( this is kept outside listview) and one search button.

Now i need to access two literal control from listview which are kept in layout template and emptydatatemplate and assign the dropdownlist value to those literal control with few extra text.

what i tried was for layout template:

```
protected void lvP_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dlCategory.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            (lvP.FindControl("ltHeaderText") as Literal).Text = " Products in " + dlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and for empty data i tried below

```
protected void lvPr_ItemCreated(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.EmptyItem)
        {
            (lvP.FindControl("ltEmptyData") as Literal).Text = "No products in " + dlCategory.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        }
    }
```

aspx markup

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvP" runat="server" OnLayoutCreated="lvP_LayoutCreated"
            OnItemCreated="lvP_ItemCreated">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table class="PWorld" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <span>
                                    <asp:Literal ID="ltHeaderText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr id="itemplaceHolder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <td>
                        <table class="PWorldInner" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img height="65px" width="175px" src='<%#Eval("ProductLogo")%>' alt="<%#Eval("pName")%>" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <asp:Literal ID="ltEmptyData" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: So did it work what you've tried ? If not, please provide also the exception or what didn't work.

Comment: No it didn't work. I get Null error. "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Where do you get the `NullReferenceException`, in `LayoutCreated` or   `ItemCreated` or in both? Please show also the `ListView` aspx markup.

Comment: I get Null referencfe exception in both. I have addedd the aspx markup in question

Comment: You have posted the markup but i don't see a control with ID `ltHeaderText`.

Comment: sorry...type error. i took the page code from test page. i will update that.